# How to dock Chrome Web Inspector to the side of the browser instead of the bottom?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

It's currently docked to the bottom of the browser.

I know it can be split into a separate window, but I wanted it docked to the side of the browser instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<del>Click on the gear in the lower right of the inspector. Check the `Dock to right` option.</del> You may have to update to the beta/dev channel for the option to be available.

Update: The option is now in the lower left of the inspectors toolbar.

[image: New toggle button for "dock to right"]

Comment: @TryingToImprove try holding the mouse button when you click on the icon

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to tell that for Google Chrome 24 the `dock to right` have been moved to the bottom left. You have to hold down the icon.

Take a look at this chrome issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154199

Answer (score 5):

At the top right of the inspector, click the button with the three dots:

[image]

A subwindow will appear. There are three buttons beside the text "Dock side"; click on the third:

[image]

That's all.